# Are there any APIs for programmatically translating text on the server-side?

Tags: java, javascript, client-side, server-side, google-translate

I've looked at Google Translate but from what I can tell it only offers a client-side JavaScript API for freely translating text between languages.

What I need to do is translate text on the server side in Java. Is there a library that makes it possible to do this for free with Google Translate?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Java API...

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/

and just for reference, a PHP implementation -

http://code.google.com/p/gtranslate-api-php/

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing limiting the Google Translate API to client side code. There is a [RESTful Google Translate interface](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html) available. You are free to consume this API from the client side or from javascript-originated requests from the browser. I have implemented a text localizing service using this API from the server side in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, for anyone that comes here and is looking for a more up to date answer, there is the [Google Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/overview) which is Google's fuller translation package, with the "Advanced" version being server-side only ([does not allow API keys](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/editions)).

It comes with an [official Java client](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v3/java).

Also, it is free for the ["First 500,000 characters* per month"](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing).