# How to sort list which comprised chinese characters too

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have a list with string, which some contains some chinese characters:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("安卓");
list.add("iPhone");
list.add("WindowsMobile");
list.add("苹果");
list.add("Ubuntu");
list.add("Windows7");
```

How do I sort it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the normal sort eg:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

If you need some custom sorting you can implement your own comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
         // some own compare method...
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Collections.sort using your own comparator would definitely be a start. To create a comparator, have a class implement `Comparator` and implement its compare method. Then, instantiate an object and pass it to the Collections.sort method.

**EDIT:**

Approx psuedocode for the logic inside the compare method:

```
IF s1 isChinese && s2 isEnglish
    return -1
IF s2 isChinese && s1 isEnglish
    return 1
IF s1 isChinese && s2 isChinese 
    //implement your custom way to sort stuff
IF s1 isEnglish && s2 isEnglish 
    //implement your custom way to sort stuff
```

This way, your chinese words will appear at the top instead of at the bottom.

Comment: i already tried, while the result showed that chinese characters were located at the bottom..i want it display according the first alphabet not the language

Comment: your compare method was not implemented properly then. returning -1 indicates that the first param of the compare method will be placed before the second in your list. returning 0 means param1 and param2 will have no particular ordering. returning 1 indicates param2 is to be placed before.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to translate it to english [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201769/are-there-any-apis-for-programmatically-translating-text-on-the-server-side) and then sort it using Comparator..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Collator.getInstance(Locale.CHINESE)`,the code:

```
Collections.sort(yourlist, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Stringa1, Stringa2) {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.CHINESE);
        int mySort = collator.compare(a1, a2);
        return mySort;
    }
 });
```